# Disable clustered index from entire model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using GUID for all my database entities, so, it's recommended to not work with clustered index.
How can I intercept model builder to instruct EF Core 2 to not create any clustered index on primary keys?

Comment: It's usually best to have a clustered index. It doesn't have to be the same as the primary key.

Comment: Agree @Damien_The_Unbeliever but i have to disable the clustered index for all the primary keys, after this, i'll add a "dumb" clustered index column just to help SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no such setting/option control. So as usual in such cases, you can put a loop at the end of the `OnModelCreating` (to make sure all entity types are discovered) which iterates the entity types and modifies their PK relational (or in this case SqlServer) attributes:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    var key = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();
    key.SqlServer().IsClustered = false;
}
```